# Grab Value from HTML Table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table with the following values:

```
<tr class="tuker1">
  <td class="tuker-lft1">
    Username
  </td> 
  <td class="tuker-rght1" onclick="awardRoute()">
    <a href="#">
      AWARD ROUTE
    </a> 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

When I click the AWARD ROUTE link I would like the value inside "tuker-lft1" to go into the function variable.

```
awardRoute() {
  var username = "";
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You need plain js or a jQuery solution would be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only have one element on the page with the class `tuker-lft1`:

```
function awardRoute() {
    var username = $('.tuker-lft1').text();
}
```

If you want the text of the previous cell (i.e. the cell to the left), you can use sibling tree traversal functions:

```
function awardRoute() {
    var username = $(this).prev('td').text();
}

$('.tuker-rght1').click(awardRoute);
```

If you want the text in the cell that has the class `tuker-lft1` within the same row as the cell you're clicking on, regardless of where the cell is, use parent/child tree traversal functions:

```
function awardRoute() {
    var username = $(this).parent().children('.tuker-lft1').text();
}

$('.tuker-rght1').click(awardRoute);
```

Note that in the last two examples, you should remove the onclick attribute from your HTML.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is

Comment: the way you had it have to pass `this` as argument from markup, then use  `awardRoute(elem){ $(elem).prev()...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it like this:

```
<td class="tuker-rght1" onclick="$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html()"><a href="#"> AWARD ROUTE </a> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="tuker1">
   <td class="tuker-lft1"> Username </td> 
   <td class="tuker-rght1"> <a href="#"> AWARD ROUTE </a> </td> 
</td>

$(function(){
    $('.tuker-rght1').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $(this).prev().html();

        console.log(username);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var username = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tuker-lft1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/2jDr6/)

Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Username
        </td> 
        <td class="award">
            Award
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var awards = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.award'));
awards.forEach(function(award){
    award.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var parentNode = this.parentNode;
        var username = parentNode.querySelector('td').innerHTML;
        alert(username);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

```
var username = $(".tuker-lft1").val()
```

Comment: `.val()`? I think that is only for inputs